# Memory leaks with absolutely no reason

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, socket.io, v8

So I have this simplest socket.io example:

```
'use strict';

const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080, function () {

});

io.on("connection",function(socket){

    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {

    });

    socket.on('sync', function(data) {

    });

    socket.on('enter', function(data) {

    });
});
```

I tested this code with some simple Artillery.io script that just simulates 60 users coming during 60 seconds and sending 600 pointless 'sync' messages each. I have created some heap snapshots and discovered that memory is constantly being allocated by **(array)**, **(compiled code)** and **(system)** constructors. Actually I see allocation and deleting of memory but the delta is still always positive:

[image]

In **(array)** constructor I see some *'deoptimization_data'*, *'transitions'* and other probably internal V8 objects. When I look into Retainers tab I see that this objects are somehow referenced by different node.js and socket.io objects. If you run this project by yourself and take a few heap snapshots with Chrome DevTools you will probably see the same thing.

I also have my own app (simple game using socket.io that I tested without artillery.io) and when I take heap snapshots while playing my game I notice that I have no memory leaks related with my own objects (thank God XD) but I still get same continuous allocation of memory with the same **(array)**, **(compiled code)** and **(system)** constructors. And I see again this *'deoptimization_data'*, *'transitions'* and other V8 objects. It looks something like this:

[image]

This three constructors are slowly consuming my memory even with the most simplest socket.io example that I could create. What are they and what can I do with them to stop memory leaks?